# Three20 just giving a black screen?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, three20

I'm currently building a project using **Three20 (v 1.0.4)**. It builds and runs with no errors or warnings. It's simply the AppDelegate and a TTLauncher class.

### AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Three20/Three20.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
}

@end
```

### AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "LauncherController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

//=============================================================
// UIApplicationDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{
    TTNavigator* navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
    navigator.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeAll;
    TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;
    [map from:@"*" toViewController:[TTWebController class]];
    [map from:@"tt://launcher" toViewController:[LauncherController class]];
    [navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://launcher"]];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)URL
{
    [[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:URL.absoluteString]];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

### LauncherController.h

```
#import <Three20/Three20.h>


@interface LauncherController : TTViewController <TTLauncherViewDelegate> 
{
    TTLauncherView* _launcherView;
}

@end
```

### LauncherController.m

```
#import "LauncherController.h"


@implementation LauncherController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])
    {
        self.title = @"Launcher Screen";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    _launcherView = [[TTLauncherView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    _launcherView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _launcherView.delegate = self;
    _launcherView.columnCount = 2;
    _launcherView.pages =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
     [[[TTLauncherItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Position" image:@"bundle://ic_positions2.png" URL:nil] autorelease], nil];
    [self.view addSubview:_launcherView];
}

- (void)launcherView:(TTLauncherView*)launcher didSelectItem:(TTLauncherItem*)item {
}

- (void)launcherViewDidBeginEditing:(TTLauncherView*)launcher {
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                                 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                 target:_launcherView action:@selector(endEditing)] autorelease] animated:YES];
}

- (void)launcherViewDidEndEditing:(TTLauncherView*)launcher {
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Any thoughts on why I'd get the following screen?

[image: Blank screen, iPhone Simulator]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check your main.m file for the following line:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

You will need to change the last parameter to a string containing the name of your app delegate. In your case, you would write:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you! Here's the documentation if anyone is interested: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain Basically, the argument I changed was delegateClassName, originally it was 'nil' meaning that I was loading the delegate from my application's Main nib file. With Three20 I don't need a nib file and had deleted it, but it was still trying to load it, specifying my app delegate as featherless suggested, rectified the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check if the main window of app delegate is made visible and the necessary view is added to the main window.

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.window addSubview:startingview];
```

Comment: This is done automatically in Three20 when using `TTNavigator`.